# How do I archive a folder keeping owners and permissions intact?

Tags: permissions, tar, file-copy

Is there any way to archive a folder and keep the owners and permissions intact? I'm doing a backup of some files, which I want to move using a usb-stick, which has a FAT filesystem. So the idea was to keep all this information and file setting within an archive.

I know that the `-p` option for `tar` keeps the permissions, but still not the ownership.

Comment: tar should do this by default. If you extract as superuser (required to be able to set file ownership at all), it will set the owners to data stored in the archive unless you tell it not to.

Comment: By a little bit more thinking I could have come to this … Thank you very much. I guess this is actually the answer, do you want to post it as such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tar's default mode is to preserve ownership and permissions on archive creation; I don't believe there's even an option not to store the data. When you extract an archive, if you're a normal user, the default is to use stored permissions minus the umask and set the owner to whoever's extracting; if you're superuser, the default is to use stored permissions and ownership verbatim. There are options to control how these metadata are restored on extraction (see the man page).

Answer (score 1):

Whether a file can be assigned a different user id (e.g. while extracting a `tar`archive) does not depend on whether you are superuser but on whether you have the permission to do so. There are several possible reasons why you may have this permission:

1) you are on HP-UX where this is generally permitted. This is seen to be a security risk.

2) you have the fine grained permission to change the owner of local files and you are working on a local filesystem. See e.g. `man privileges` and the typical fine grained permission `PRIV_FILE_CHOWN` and `PRIV_FILE_CHOWN_SELF`

3) The directory where the files are extracted has an inheritable ACL `write_owner` set.